# Error when installing ruby 3.0.2 on MAC: Error running '__rvm_make -j8' error

Tags: ruby

I am trying to install Ruby 3.0.2 on my Mac and keep getting this error message:
Error running '__rvm_make -j8'

Any idea what this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

- `xcode-select --install`
- `rvm pkg install openssl`
- `rvm install XXX --with-openssl-dir=brew --prefix openssl`

Comment: Unrecognized command line flag: '--prefix'

Answer (score 0):

Should enclose command inside "$()"

> rvm install XXX --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)